# React - onmouseenter doesn't work between child elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to implement a menu that shows up on hover. The problem is that the menu hides while hovering between the DropdownOption child elements, so whenever I hover between options 1 and 2. Each child is a div and has a margin of 0px

```
  openDropdown = () => {
    this.setState({showList: true})
  }

  closeDropdown = () => {
    this.setState({showList: false})
  }

  showList = () => {
    return (
      <DropdownContainer onMouseEnter={this.openDropdown} onMouseLeave={this.closeDropdown}>
          <DropdownOption>Option1</DropdownOption>
          <DropdownOption>Option2</DropdownOption>
      </DropdownContainer>
    )
  }

render () {
    return (
      <div onMouseEnter={this.openDropdown}>
        <MenuButtonContainer>
          Title
        </MenuButtonContainer>
        {this.state.showList ? this.showList() : null}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an event bubbling issue.

Where you have your event listener callbacks, e.g.:

```
openDropdown = () => {
  this.setState({showList: true})
}
```

Try accessing the `event` object by including it as a parameter to the function. Then on the event object, call `stopPropagation()` E.g:

```
openDropdown = (event) => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  this.setState({showList: true})
}
```